# Vite equivalent for requirejs shim deps

Tags: requirejs, vite

I'm looking to use vite for an old project. But one of the dependencies depends on JQuery, in RequireJS config, it's listed with the dependency `jquery` in the `deps` array in `shims`.
i.e.

```
        shims: {
            'dependency-name': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            ...
        }
```

I want to achieve the same using Vite.